# How does C# console application read input from PhP

Tags: c#, php, visual-studio

I am using windows 8.1, 64bit OS, PHP Version 5.6.19 and Visual Studio 2015. I want my C# console application to read input from PhP. Means i will insert input in PhP and my C# console application will read that input from my PhP file. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Does this php input is stored on the file system?
If the answer is Yes so you can just open the file with File.ReadAllText method and there is no nothing to do with php only reading from files.
If you want your c# program that will access to php program on runtime so this is far more complicate.